# Concatenating a str to an auto incrementeed column which functions as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, load-data-infile

Having some trouble putting together a table with a unique value. The current setup I have for two tables which for all intents and purposes can be the same as the one below. My problem is that I'm trying to use the auto incremented value as the primary key due to redundancies in the data pulls, but since it's for two tables, I want to concatenate a string to the auto incremented value so my ID column would be:
Boop1, Boop2, Boop3 and Beep1, Beep2, Beep3, instead of 1, 2, 3 for both tables so they are differentiated and thus do not have duplicate values when I put in constraints

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beep`.`boop` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`a` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`b` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`c` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`d` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'blah.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES SET DCMID = CONCAT('DCM'+`DCMID`);
```

The code in boldface is optional and was only there to try concatenating which I already know does not work

I realize that this would not be able to work since my datatype is an INT, so what would I have to do to to keep my autoincrement while differentiating

For reference, I am using a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, and not INSERT (and I don't  think bulk insert is available with mySQL workbench). otherwise, i would bulk insert and just utilize last_insert_id

The goal is to plug and play for a datapull I perform so I can archive my data quickly and run queries to grab the data I need in the future. using one insert line per row of data i have would be extremely inefficient

I was utilizing a delimiter function earlier with a trigger, which in theory would have worked by altering the table after the load data infile, but that requires SUPER privileges which I do not have

is what i'm asking for even possible, or should i give up and find a workaround, or try grabbing super priveleges and trying the delimiter trigger

Comment: You cant enter a value for an auto increment value. Thats kind of the point. You can always enter a different unique id. Why does it even have to auto increment if you are going to control what gets entered?

Comment: because I would like it to autoincrement with a prefix for differentiation. i think i also might be confusing myself since i was using composite keys which ended up having duplicate values. i'm just extremely averse to having duplicate values.

Comment: would it work to have another field to fill the role of your concatenated part? something like type? or even just call it prefix..

Comment: are you saying that i make two separate columns with one as an auto increment, and concatenate the two into the the 'prefix' column which will serve as my primary key?

Comment: I dont understand why the format of the primary key matters. Why does your entered data have to be part of the primary key?

Comment: yea i think i might just be confusing myself. like i said earlier i was using a composite key and was running into a bunch of duplicate values so i guess im just trying to avoid that as much as possible

Comment: just have an auto increment int as your primary key and any other information you need to store do so in regular fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would do that, but you could use two different indexes. The first one is the auto-increment, and is populated by MySQL. The second one is your "prefixed" key, and is created by a trigger called after insert, where you update the column based on the first key and the prefix that you want.