# how to generate auto increment column which will be have some pattern in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named dept_registration it has a column dept_code so I have to make this field auto-generate but in a specific pattern.

example:- test0001
test0002
test0003
test0004

the "test" should be appended before number automatically  after insertion

Comment: refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425863/concatenating-a-str-to-an-auto-incrementeed-column-which-functions-as-primary-ke)

Answer (score 2):

The column definition could be

```
dept_code text DEFAULT 'test' || lpad(nextval('myseq')::text, 4, '0')
```

where `myseq` is a sequence.

You will get in trouble once the counter reaches 10000...